# Ubuntu 22.04 Firefox does not download file to Desktop

Tags: firefox, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 an noticed that Firefox does not allow me download a file to the Desktop.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I do not confirm. Firefox snap on Lubuntu 22.04 downloads files to desktop.

Comment: and works in 22.04 too. I think you need to [edit] your question to provide more details of what steps you are taking to achieve this. I just clicked on the hamburger menu (top right corner of FF) selected `Save page as` navigated to `Home` and selected `Desktop`.

Comment: @24601 If I `Save page as` on `Desktop` it does not give an error, but the files are nowhere to be found on my `Desktop`.

Comment: Oups! you're right... just tried it and nothing in the `Desktop` folder. Report it as a bug to mozilla... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1188220

Comment: Also confirmed. Reviewing syslog, looks like an AppArmor denial. Not too hard to fix once it's reported.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a GTK problem, that is already fixed and merged into the codebase, but not released for ubuntu yet.

I found another tipp on that though, that works for me:
When you have the save dialog open, click the filename field (only focus needed) and then save it normally.

**Found that here:** https://forum.vivaldi.net/post/579271

Comment: This workaround resolves it. Just click the filename field to de-select it. :+1:

Comment: Gnome issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4907

Answer (score -2):

### See [OCDev's](https://askubuntu.com/users/557743/ocdev) comment, my answer is incorrect

As [SimonEritsch](https://askubuntu.com/a/1408534/1406803) stated, Mozilla seems to be aware of the issue and I'd imagine a fix will come soon. In the meantime, I highly recommend installing Firefox via apt. Canonical (the company that develops Ubuntu) is *really* pushing snap, so it takes a few extra steps, but you can find those steps [here.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Not a problem with Firefox. This happens for all Ubuntu file save dialogs for all web browsers. Workaround is to click the filename field to de-select it, then save.